# submit on enter, reactive form with only radio buttons angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-reactive-forms

I have a `form` which only contains `radio buttons` as inputs. I also have a `submit button` which submits the `form`. But I would like to submit the `form` on hitting **enter key**. Below is what I've so far.

```
<form [formGroup]="verificationOption" (keyup.enter)="sendVerificationCode()" (ngSubmit)="sendVerificationCode()">
    <input type="radio" formControlName="verificationType" [value]="message" checked>
    <span class="text_radio_space"> Text Message</span><br/><br/>
    <input type="radio" formControlName="verificationType" [value]="voicecall">
    <span class="text_radio_space"> Voice Call</span><br/><br/>
    <div class="text-right">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-design-auth">Send Code </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

By default, the first option will be selected and when user hits enter the form is supposed to get submitted. I've added `(keyup.enter)` to the `form` but this doesn't seem to work as expected. Also if user selects any other option or switches to different option and when `enter` is hit, `form` submission happens **twice**. This is because of `(ngSubmit)` and `(keyup.enter)` on the `form`. How can I prevent `form submission` happening twice in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your issue :

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-design-auth">Send Code </button>
```

Replace with this :

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-design-auth" value="Send Code">
```

This will enable the submition with the enter key. Remove all of your `(keyup.enter)` listeners, you won't need it anymore.

Comment: That helped bro.. Thanks much.. :)